# Pip does not work unless I install Python 3.11 from Microsoft Store (Windows 11)

Tags: python, pip, windows-11

I have downloaded Python 3.11.4. When I try using pip, it says "pip is not recogized as an internal or external command...".

I tried downloading Python 3.11 from Microsoft Store, which fixes pip, but has some issues with the program I am trying to run. I have also tried reinstalling python from both, python.org and from Microsoft Store. Please let me know if you need more clarification or if you can help.

Answer (score 1):

make sure you checked `Add python 3.xx to PATH` like in image [image]

Comment: That helps, Command Prompt recognizes Python, but Powershell does not unless I download the app. When I download the app, it messes with my project. Should I install the app?

Comment: tye Solution in https://www.educative.io/answers/err-python-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command,
add path of python script to system Environment variables